# no jsmile in java.library.path

Tags: java, netbeans, dll, library-path

I am getting exception : `no jsmile in java.library.path` when i run my project. Even i have added `jsmile_win64` in lib folder and `.dll` file in vm option : `-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\admin\jsmile.dll";` But still I am facing the same issue.

```
import smile.Network;
import smile.learning.DataMatch;
import smile.learning.DataSet;
import smile.learning.EM;
import smile.learning.GreedyThickThinning;
public class MyClass 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Network _net = new Network();
      _net.readFile(workfilehere);
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine after changed the `-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\admin\jsmile.dll";` to `-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\admin\"`